# Why беСхвостый but беЗфюзеляжный?

Tags: правописание

Why беСхвостый but беЗфюзеляжный? I thought it should be "c" in the latter case as well because the ф is voiceless.

Comment: Видать, летчики боятся фюзеляжного беса :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've never met this word in print, but I'm pretty sure it should be *бесфюзеляжный*, similarly to *бесфамильный* or *бесформенный*.